# Enviar parametro adicional en un formulario get

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, formularios, asp.net-core, asp

Necesito enviar dos parametros al action por medio de un formulario get.

Uno de ellos esta definido como @ViewData y el otro se recoge del input del formulario.

El caso es que de la manera que lo estoy haciendo solo me recoge el parametro introducido en el input y no recoge el parametro introducido en asp-route...

Mi idea es que la ruta acabe siendo algo asi:

https://localhost:44367/Tipos/Index?tipo=IN&SearchString=A

Pero esto es lo que consigo ahora mismo:

https://localhost:44367/Tipos/Index?SearchString=A

```
<form asp-controller="Tipos" asp-action="Index" asp-route-tipo="@ViewData["ty"]" method="get">
    <p>
        Buscar: <input type="text" name="SearchString"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Alguien sabe como pordria solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano :3

Comment: no puedes poner un input más en ese form? como type hidden?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Muchas gracias, asi me ha funcionado